# How to create a .htaccess file for php?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been created web pages and run in loclahost,

I need to remove the .php extension from a PHP file for example `localhost/root folder-name/wallpaper.php` to `localhost/root folder-name/wallpaper`.

I search the Google, and i found like a link http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Here is the `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

May i know, is there possible to achieve this one in localhost?

If possible means, how to create `.htaccess` file? I means, what is the name have to use to save `.htaccess` file?

Anybody can help me? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the file in Microsoft Wordpad or Notepad and save it to the name `.htaccess` (note that older versions of Notepad do not allow this). The filename has just an extension with NO name before the dot. Some programs will not allow you to save a filename with just an extension and Windows Explorer will not allow you to rename a file with just an extension as well.

Comment: if i create .htaccess, it didn't allow.. it shows, "you must type a file name" may i know, what to do? thanks

Comment: Are you using Windows? If so, create the file with Notepad. Some other programs will not allow this, but Notepad will.

Comment: yes i m using windows, and i used notepad only,, but i didn't.

Comment: If you are using the command `File, Save` and type in `.htaccess` it should work. I have also tested it with Wordpad. What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: It looks like the old versions of Notepad didn't allow this. Try Wordpad.

Comment: Open a dos window with `Start - Run` and type `cmd.exe`. In the dos window type `copy con .htaccess `<press enter>

When typing the above line the cursor moves down one line to a blank line. Create the file line by line. Once you are ready to create the file press enter to get to a blank line and then press and hold Ctrl Z. This returns a ^Z. Once this has been entered press enter to save and exit the file.  You should then be able to edit the file in Wordpad or Notepad and resave it without problem. See: [this link](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000398.htm)

Comment: Following is a link with more complete instructions. Go to: [this link](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000398.htm)

Comment: Alternatively, you should be able to find the `MS DOS` command prompt with `Start - All Programs - Accessories - Command Prompt`. It may be in a slightly different location on your version of Windows but it will be called `Command Prompt`

Comment: If you can't make any of the above work, try downloading [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.7.4.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let's walk through this file. The first thing that we do here is wrap everything in a check for the existence of mod_rewrite.c; if that Apache module is present, we can continue. We then turn the RewriteEngine On and prepare it to work by giving it two rules. These rules say to perform a Rewrite if the requested URI does not match an existing file or directory name.

In the next line declares the actual RewriteRule. This says that any requests to api/v1/ that is not an existing file or directory should instead be sent to api/v1/index.php. The (.*) marks a named capture, which is sent along to the MyAPI.php script as well in the request variable through the use of the $1 delimiter. At the end of that line are some flags that configure how the rewrite is performed. Firstly, [QSA] means that the named capture will be appended to the newly created URI. Second [NC] means that our URIs are not case sensitive. Finally, the [L] flag indicates that mod_rewrite should not process any additional rules if this rule matches.